# Android Dynamic String: %1d vs %1$d

Tags: android, string, string-formatting, android-resources

Is there a difference between a format string with the $ included?

`%1d` vs `%1$d`

I noticed that in the app code we have both and both seems to work ok.

or by the way using `%1d to %2d` vs `%1$d to %2$d`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> `%d` - just display number

```
int first = 10;
System.out.printf("%d", first);
// output:
// 10
```

---

> `%1d` - display number with information how much space should be "reserved" (at least one)

```
int first = 10;
System.out.printf("->%1d<-", first);
// output:
// ->10<-
```

> `%9d` - reserve "9" chars (if number will be shorter - put spaces there) and align to right

```
int first = 10;
System.out.printf("->%9d<-", first);
// output:
// ->       10<-
//   123456789
```

> `%-9d` - same as above but align to LEFT (this `minus` is important)

```
int first = 10;
System.out.printf("->%-9d<-", first);
// output:
// ->10       <-
//   123456789
```

---

> `%1$d` - use (in format) position of the element from varargs (so you can REUSE elements instead of passing them two times)

```
int first = 10;
int second = 20;
System.out.printf("%1$d %2$d %1$d", first, second);
// output:
// 10 20 10
```

---

> `%1$9d` - mix two of them. Get first parameter (`1$`) and reserve nine chars (`%9d`)

```
int first = 10;
System.out.printf("->%1$9d<-", first);
// output:
// ->       10<-
//   123456789
```

Answer (score 2):

see [java.util.Formatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter) ...it's called "explicit argument indices".

while referring to 1 single index, this makes no difference, because the order cannot be changed. the most common use might be, to substitute twice within the same string, while passing one argument.

the full pattern looks alike this:

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

Comment: I don't understand you, can you give an example?

Comment: @htafoya in the short-form, it's `%` position (which is a 1 based index) then `$` and the data-type... where the position refers to the order of arguments, which follows the string, eg. when using `String.format()`. the linked documentation has various examples, in short and long form.

Comment: I understand the % part, but I don't get why the `$` is needed, i have used with and without the `$` indistinctly.   The link doesn't give any explanation of its use.

Comment: @htafoya the full pattern explains it... `%` indicates the beginning of the string substitution and the `$` terminates the argument index.

Comment: Then why it works if I don't use the $,  it should fail the regex

Comment: @htafoya the argument index is optional - and it defaults to the natural order of arguments, being assigned 1:1... so this syntax is merely good for reordering the indexes; eg. when different languages require a different order, this provides the necessary flexibility - or when substituting values twice.

Comment: Thank you, I think that you are misreading the question and answering "read the docs" instead of actually answering what is asked, after reading the docs I understand. The answer to the question should be: "NO they are NOT equal: by not placing the $ you are using the `width` flag instead of the `argument` flag, so what you are really coding is that the string would be formatted as minimum 1 and 2 characters"

Comment: @htafoya well, you've edited the initial question. without the `$` as terminator for the argument index, it seems to be interpreted as the `width` parameter; as your example output suggests. I wasn't aware before that it's optional; so I've learned something, too.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same question: THEY ARE NOT THE SAME

for the example posted:

> `%1d to %2d` vs `%1$d to %2$d`

As Martin shared, the format pattern is:

`%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`

By not placing the `$`, the regex uses the `%1`, `%2` and so on for the following regex arguments.

`flags` needs some specific values, so the `1` and `2` are being used as the `width` argument, which specifies the **minimum width**. If you continued with the same pattern you would end up with something as:

```
String.format("Hello: '%1d' '%2d' '%3d' '%4d'", 1, 2, 3, 4);
==> Hello: '1' ' 2' '  3' '   4'
```

Of course, as the `width` argument is being used, the %number won't represent the argument order as desired:

```
String.format("Hello: '%4d' '%3d' '%2d' '%1d'", 1, 2, 3, 4);
    ==> Hello: '   1' '  2' ' 3' '4'
```